# Proper null check

Tags: c#, oop, properties, null

I am instantiating an Associate object and assigning properties to it from txtboxes inside of my main form.  What is the best practice for null checking?  Is it to check each and every property with an if statement before I assign it or is there something a bit better?  Here is my code:

```
Associate updateAssociate = new Associate();

updateAssociate.AssocID = txtAssocId.Text;
updateAssociate.FirstName = txtFname.Text;
updateAssociate.LastName = txtLname.Text;
updateAssociate.HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtHireDate.Text);
updateAssociate.ContractEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtContractEnd.Text);
updateAssociate.TerminationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTerminationDate.Text);
updateAssociate.FullPartTimeID = cboFullPart.SelectedText;
updateAssociate.PrimaryRole = cboPRole.SelectedText;
```

Comment: What exactly you expect to be null? All controls will always exist, unless you have the code in the wrong place to begin with. (Or creating the controls yourself on the fly?)

Comment: I would expect that you have some sort of validation at the UI where you don't let the user create and `Associate` unless the required fields are populated. The remainder should be `string.Empty`.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear the contents of the control.  If it is a text box then it would be the .Text property I would want to check for null or blank values before I assign them to the object.

Comment: @VinnyGuitara: It's still not really clear what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve.  There doesn't seem to be a high probability of null references in the posted code, unless something else is wrong.  For any given property being assigned, what else would you want to do if the value is null?

Comment: @David.... so if my form is populated from the database and then I go to instantiate an object of Associate from the text fields I am trying to handle if one of these fields returned from the DB is null.

Comment: I don't really see any issue just let it "fail fast".... unless the .Text is never null and it produces a blank string: updateAssociate.FirstName = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(updateAssociate.FirstName) ? updateAssociate.FirstName : null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment to the question:

> If it is a text box then it would be the .Text property I would want to check for null or blank values before I assign them to the object

You can use the null coalescing operator to check for null values when assigning like that:

```
updateAssociate.AssocID = txtAssocId.Text ?? string.Empty;
```

or:

```
updateAssociate.AssocID = txtAssocId.Text ?? someDefaultValue;
```

That way if `txtAssocId.Text` is `null` then you would assign your defined default to the object property instead of `null`.

Though I'm not entirely sure a `TextBox`'s `.Text` property would ever *be* `null` instead of an empty string.  Maybe you want to check for both?:

```
updateAssociate.AssocID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAssocId.Text) ? someDefaultValue : txtAssocId.Text;
```

Comment: I think this is the answer, what about combobox value property.  If the combobox is empty the value property would be null, correct?  If so how would I handle that?  I have this: 
        updateAssociate.Location = (cboLocation.SelectedValue ?? string.Empty).ToString();

Comment: @VinnyGuitara: It certainly could potentially be slightly different for any given control, particularly with things like `ComboBox.SelectedValue` where the type is `object`.  But the overall principle is the same.  Wherever you want to check for `null` or some other undesirable value in your logic, you'd simply check for it.  Could be as simple as a null coalescing operator (or null conditional operator in C#6+), could be as complex as a multi-line `if` block.  Either way, a conditional operation is a conditional operation.

Comment: I wanted to try to use the null coalescing as it looks much cleaner.  Is there a way to use that on the object type?

Comment: @VinnyGuitara: The only restriction you're likely to run into is that the result type of an operation has to be determined at compile time.  So in-line conditions such as the null coalescing operator or the ternary conditional operator need to, in and of themselves, "advertise" a single possible result type.  Do you have an example of one that isn't working as such?

Comment: I have somethign like this now:
            updateAssociate.FullPartTimeID = cboFullPart.SelectedText ?? string.Empty;
            updateAssociate.PrimaryRole = cboPRole.SelectedText ?? string.Empty;
            updateAssociate.SystemDomain = cboDomain.SelectedText ?? string.Empty;
  if (txtTerminationDate.Text != null || txtTerminationDate.Text != string.Empty)
                updateAssociate.TerminationDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtTerminationDate.Text ?? string.Empty);

Comment: @VinnyGuitara: And is there something that isn't working in any of that?  Try to focus on a single non-working statement.  Multiple lines of code don't work well in comments, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Here is an exapmle of a non-working one:
            if (txtContractEnd.Text != null || txtContractEnd.Text != string.Empty)
                updateAssociate.ContractEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtContractEnd.Text ?? string.Empty);

If the txtbox is empty it still passes that test and tries to convert a blank string to date and fails.

Comment: @VinnyGuitara: You can try using `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead of comparing to `null` and `string.Empty` manually.  Additionally, even if the string isn't empty it's still wise to use something like `DateTime.TryParse()` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime()` to avoid unnecessary exceptions in un-parseable values.  String parsing is simply more involved than a simple null check, so it's going to be more code.

Comment: string.isnullorempty() was the answer.  I will also be using tryparse instead of convert.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 6 it would be [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

```
updateAssociate.AssocID = txtAssocId?.Text;
```

In prior versions of c# you can write a method to eliminate code duplication. Something like this:

```
public static T CheckNull<T>(Func<T> canBeNull) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            return canBeNull();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

And use it like this

```
updateAssociate.AssocID = CheckNull(() => txtAssocId.Text);
```

Then you can wrap any code that can throw a null reference into lambda, pass it to this method and no longer bother with it.

Comment: This looks interesting.  How would I implement this in the above code?

Comment: `return item == null ? default(T) : item;` equals to `return item;` since `default(T) == null` when `T` is *class*

Comment: @Dmitry Maybe. This solution is to mimic null-conditional operator. You don't need to rewrite code, just wrap it into lambda and that's it.

Comment: This really should have two generic types.  The input (item before the `?.`) and the output (item after the `?.`) if you want to mimic `?.`.

Comment: @jugarr why would you need the type before `?.`? It must be reference type, that is all that matters.